# How do I render an array (strings) of components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render the array of text when I load the page:

`'values': ['hello', 'world']`

but it's giving me an error. In my `formatoc.js` , I have:

```
var props = {
    'name' : 'form',
    'timer' : 1500,
    'callback' : function(id, validity, value) {console.log(id, validity, value);},
    'values': ['hello', 'world'],
    'newParent' : new FormatOC.Parent({

        "one": {"__array__":"unique", "__type__":"string","__minimum__":1,"__maximum__":200,"__component__":"Input"}

    })

}

React.render(React.createElement(ParentComponent, props), document.getElementById('react-component'));
```

This is what I have in my `Parent.jsx` file:

define(['react', 'r_foc_node'], function(React, NodeComponent) {

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {

        if(!this.props.newParent) {
            throw "ParentComponent requires newParent property";
        }

        return {
            "values": {}
        }
    },

    recursive : function(level) {

        that = this;

        console.log(level);

        for (keys in level) {
            console.log("This is a key: ", keys);

            if ((typeof level[keys]) === "object") {
                if (level[keys].constructor.name === "Parent") {
                    console.log('I am a parent');
                    level = level[keys].details();
                    //console.log(level[keys].get([key_list[0]]));
                    this.recursive(level);
                    //console.log(level[keys].keys());
                } else {
                    console.log('I am a node');
                    //console.log(level[keys]);
                };

            };

        }
    },

    childChange: function(name, valid, value) {

        this.state.values[name] = value;
        this.setState(this.state);

        console.log(name,value);


        // Call parent callback
        this.props.callback(
            this.props.name,
            this.props.newParent.valid(this.state.values),
            this.state.values
        );
    },

    render: function() {
        var that = this;

        var level = this.props;

        return (
            <div id = "form">
            {level.newParent.keys().map(function(k) {
                return (
                    <div>
                    {(level.newParent.get(k).constructor.name === "Parent") ?
                    <ParentComponent
                        name={k}
                        key={k}
                        timer={that.props.timer}
                        callback={that.childChange}
                        values={that.props.values[k]}
                        newParent={that.props.newParent.get(k)}
                    />
                    :
                    <NodeComponent
                        name={k}
                        key={that.props.name + '.' + k}
                        timer={that.props.timer}
                        callback={that.childChange}
                        values={that.props.values[k]}
                        newNode={that.props.newParent.get(k)}
                    />
                    }
                    </div>
                )
            })
            }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I'm not sure if the error is because of the way I'm trying to access the array values? But I can't seem to get the words `hello` and `world` to be rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using: `level.newParent.keys().map(function(k) {...`
this should be: `level.values.map(function(k) {...`

Comment: It gave me an error saying that `Uncaught TypeError: level.values.keys.map is not a function`. Should `'values'` be in `newParent`?

Comment: Than you are not passing the props to Parent.jsx

Comment: If any it should be `level.values.map(...)`. Arrays don't have a `key` property.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Inside my `return()` in the Parent.jsx, is it correct for it to be `values={that.props.values[0]}`?

Comment: Where are you tring to render the values?

Comment: I edited my answer thanks to `Felix`, I made a mistake in my first post

Comment: I'm trying to render it on the page through another `formatoc.js` file

Comment: @NickProzee when I try the corrected answer, my console is giving me a `Uncaught No such node in the Parent` error

Comment: My apologies, I meant to say I'm trying to render it through this `formatoc.js` file and I have a PHP file that displays it.

Comment: `Uncaught No such node in the Parent` means that `this.props.values` or `level.values` does not exist